# JSF creates new instance of the same class for each el expression in facelets

Tags: jsf-2

I have a login page in a web application project:

```
<h:form>
    <h:messages />
    <h:inputText label="Username" value="#{login.username}" required="true" />
    <h:inputSecret label="Password" value="#{login.pass}" required="true" />
    <h:commandButton value="Accedi" action="#{login.check()}"  />
</h:form>
```

When I submit the form, jsf creates three instances of Login class (I've noticed this behavior using debugger). In this way I can't use the username and password in Login.check() method: they are both null.

Besides I've tested another more complex project I've created some time ago and it works fine: only one instance is created. I don't understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the managed bean configuration of the login bean (either annotations of the class or in `faces-config.xml`), specifically its scope. A scope of "none" would have exactly the effect you're observing. The appropriate scope would probably be "request".

Comment: Sure, the Login class is @RequestScoped and I've tried @SessionScoped too, but nothing three instances are created.

Comment: @Alf: have you also looked at faces-config.xml? I think any configuration there would override the annotation. If that's not it, creating a constructor and putting a breakpoint on it may help tracking down the problem, if you're willing to sift through the source code of your JSF implementation.

Comment: I figured out! I used javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped. Using javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped it works! Import was automatically added by netbeans. Why this ambiguity?

Comment: @Alf: unfortunate timing - one is a general standard (not just for JSF), the other a JSF-specific API that was released earlier. However, both should work and I am in fact using the javax.faces annotations in my project. Of course, this depends on the JSF implementation and/or the servlet container.